# Search using powershell

Tags: powershell

So I'm not sure if this can be accomplished, all of the answers I've seen deal with knowing the exact file name...but here it goes:

I want to search through a directory that has +-2,000 songs in it, but I don't want to have to know the whole file name (because some of them can get long and complicated). Here is an example of what I want:
I know I can display all of the contents of the directory doing this:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\My\Path\To\Songs\Here
```

But what I want to do (since that directory contains about 2,000 songs) is search so that I only have to enter a few words from the title and have only those songs that contain those words pop up. For instance:

If the full name of the file is "Everybody Dies Young" and I search for the keyword "Everybody" I want the following to pop up:

Everybody
Everybody Loves Everybody
I Can't Get With Everybody
etc
etc
etc

Is this possible to search keywords in a directory and return all filenames with those keywords? I run Windows 7 if that helps anybody at all...

Comment: Try  `Get-ChildItem -Path C:\My\Path\To\Songs\Here  -Recurse -Filter *Everybody*`

Comment: @Nkosi That works! I wish I could give you the answer credit!

Comment: `Get-Help` is your friend in powershell. Use `Get-Help Get-ChildItem` to get more documentation on that cmdlet. Use the same for any command and you will be amazed at the wealth of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-Filter` parameter

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\My\Path\To\Songs\Here -Recurse -File -Filter *Everybody*
```

Reference: [Get-ChildItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem)

> **-Filter**
>
> Specifies a filter in the provider's format or language. The value of
>   this parameter qualifies the Path parameter. The syntax of the filter,
>   including the use of wildcards, depends on the provider. Filters are
>   more efficient than other parameters, because the provider applies
>   them when retrieving the objects, rather than having Windows
>   PowerShell filter the objects after they are retrieved from the
>   provider.

Update:

To get just the file paths you can extend it like

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Filter *Everybody* | % {$_.FullName}
```

Or

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Filter *Everybody* | Foreach-Object {$_.FullName}
```

by piping the files to a for each loop and extracting the full path.

Answer (score 1):

if you want a filter more elabored you can do it:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File | where {$_.Name -like "*word1*" -and $_.Name -notlike "*word2*"} | select FullName
```